# BigDecimal bit manipulation in java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Does BigDecimal support bit manipulation? If yes, can someone please point to a good tutorial on this?

If no, what is the best method to divide a BigDecimal variable by powers of 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name suggests, a `BigDecimal` is stored in **decimal** representation. So the quickest way to divide by powers of 2 is ... to divide by powers of two. You *can* shift-left and shift-right, but [*only in base-10*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scaleByPowerOfTen%28int%29) (and even then it behaves differently from bit-shifts, because it *can* produce non-integer values).

Answer (score 8):

I think you mean [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) here. `BigDecimal` uses a decimal representation for floating point values, so it is not suited for bit manipulation.

`BigInteger` does have left and right shift operations with `.shiftLeft()` and `.shiftRight()` for multiplications/divisions by powers of two respectively, so you can use that.

It also has operations such as `.bitCount()`, `.bitLength()`, `.{clear,set}Bit()`, `.and()`, `.or()`, `.andNot()` and a few others. No bitwise not, though, since it does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks but I really meant BigDecimal! How dumb!